# system properties, justification needed

Tags: java

```
3. import java.util.*;
4. public class Values {
5. public static void main(String[] args) {
6. Properties p = System.getProperties();
7. p.setProperty("myProp", "myValue");
8. System.out.print(p.getProperty("cmdProp") + " ");
9. System.out.print(p.getProperty("myProp") + " ");
10. System.out.print(p.getProperty("noProp") + " ");
11. p.setProperty("cmdProp", "newValue");
12. System.out.println(p.getProperty("cmdProp"));
13. }
14. }
```

And given the command line invocation:

```
java -DcmdProp=cmdValue Values
```

What is the result?

A. null myValue null null

B. cmdValue null null cmdValue

C. cmdValue null null newValue

D. cmdValue myValue null cmdValue

E. cmdValue myValue null newValue

F. An exception is thrown at runtime

This question is from SCJP and answer is "E". But according to me , answer should be D because when we invoke from command-line prompt , we are setting the value of "cmdProp" = "cmdValue". So , at line 12 why its giving newValue corresponding to key cmdProp.

Answer (score 0):

Line 11 of your code changes the value of the variable, that had been defined from command-line prompt. This "overwriting" is causing the change of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

After execution of line 6, all you handle is a simple map that backs the `Properties` instance. You're not handling system properties, actually. So, at line 11 you set an entry in the map and at line 12 you read the new value of the entry you just modified.

Answer (score 0):

Because of setting cmdProp from the code just before outputing it second time:

```
11. p.setProperty("cmdProp", "newValue");
12. System.out.println(p.getProperty("cmdProp"));
```